# cannot print url data in a required format via php

Tags: php

I need to get **url data** printed in the following format below

```
https://mysite/data/api?q="'xxxxx' in contents"
```

but each time i run the code below am getting something like this below which is not what I want

```
https://mysite/data/api?q=xxxxx in contents
```

here is what I have tried

```
$my_id  = 'xxxxx';
$myurl= "https://mysite/data/api?q={$my_id}";
echo $myurl . " in contents";
```

Comment: is that apostrophe is dynamic or you want it in static?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic but if you can provide both dynamic as well as static it will also be awesome. Thanks for responding

Comment: Why do you want a double quote to quote the whole string in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this HTML code in your variable declaration:

```
<?php 
$my_id  = '&#34;&#39;xxxxx&#39;';
$myurl= "https://mysite/data/api?q={$my_id}";
echo $myurl . " in contents&#34; ";
?>
```

You will get the output like this:

```
https://mysite/data/api?q="'xxxxx' in contents"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the quotes to the query parameter, you need to

1. Include your quote to the string, and
2. Encode the query in proper url encoding.

```php
<?php

$query = http_build_query([
  'q' => "\"'xxxxxxx' in contents\"",
]);
$myurl= "https://mysite/data/api?{$query}";
echo $myurl;
```

Which would output this:

```
https://mysite/data/api?q=%22%27xxxxxxx%27+in+contents%22
```

And is effectively this when copied and paste to your browser's location bar:

```
https://mysite/data/api?q="'xxxxxxx' in contents"
```

Comment: Thanks but your code returns  `https://mysite/data/apiq=%27xxxxxxx%27 in contents`

Comment: That is the correctly encoded version of the string with quotes. Quotes themselves are not URL safe characters.